# Noise when braking at very low speed

Tags: honda, brakes, noise, disk-brakes

I have a 1998 Honda Civic Ex. My front brakes (pads/rotors/hardware) were replaced a little over a year ago.

Recently I started noticing a pulsing squeak when braking at very low speeds and brake pedal pressed about 1/4 of the way in.

Can’t hear it while hard braking. Also brake pedal does not vibrate when braking at high speeds which I’ve experienced before due to warped rotors.

The noise isn’t so much a metal on metal clicking it’s more like a squeak similar to a dry brushing making noise but it only happens when braking. If I press down on the suspension or turn the steering wheel I can’t replicate it.

Would seized caliper slide pins cause this? When the brakes were done silicone paste was used on the slide pins. Not sure if that matters but figured I’d include the info.

If it’s the brake pads shifting around, would it make a different noise other than I’m describing?

Comment: Clean the brake pads with brake cleaner and roughen them up a bit with sand paper, put on a **flat** surface. If the brake pad's pores are filled with brake dust, it makes a squeeling sound. Additionally, your anti-squeel plates may have brokendown/missing/whatever.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it. Something else I noticed is the noise doesn’t happen unless I’ve been driving around for a while. I’m guessing when the brakes are warmed up. Does that help in trying to narrow down what it could be?

Comment: On mine ('03) the brake dust shields had rusted so badly I was able to pull them off by hand, and they were rubbing against something, probably the brake rotor.

Comment: have you already resolved the noise when braking at low speed after driving for a while? I have similar problem with my Honda Jazz gd 2007. Hope i can get some advise from you in case you already diagnosed the problem...

Comment: Yes but it may not apply to your case. For me it was the rubber nose dampers at the end of the slide pins. They swelled up and would cause them to seize up. They were brand new aftermarket ones too. Replaced with oem and haven’t heard noise since. Check your slide pins make sure they move freely

Comment: @Aaathan You need to check obvious things first like what was suggested. For me it was the rubber noise dampers at the ends of the slide pins. They were swelled up and would cause the pins to get stuck in the bore